# How to set Source of s:BitmapFill dynamically? (Flash Builder, Code Inside)

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, bitmap, mxml

In Flash Builder (flex 4) I try to use next code to set selected by user (from file system) Image as a repeated background. It worked with mx:Image but I want to use cool repited capabiletis of s:BitmapFill.

BTW: Technic I use also does not work with S:BitmapImage. Also FP does not return any errors. What Shall I do with my code to make it work?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:net="flash.net.*"
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600" >

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

            private function btn_click(evt:MouseEvent):void {
                var arr:Array = [];
                arr.push(new FileFilter("Images", ".gif;*.jpeg;*.jpg;*.png"));
                fileReference.browse(arr);
            }

            private function fileReference_select(evt:Event):void {
                fileReference.load();
            }

            private function fileReference_complete(evt:Event):void {
                img.source = fileReference.data;
                Alert.show(ObjectUtil.toString(fileReference));
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <net:FileReference id="fileReference"
                           select="fileReference_select(event);"
                           complete="fileReference_complete(event);" />
    </fx:Declarations>

<s:Rect id="backgroundRect" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <s:fill>
        <s:BitmapFill id="img" source="@Embed('1.jpg')" fillMode="repeat" />
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
<mx:Button id="btn"
                       label="Browse and preview..."
                       click="btn_click(event);" />
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this code:

```
        private function fileReference_complete(evt:Event):void {           
            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.loadBytes(fileReference.data);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaderCompleteHandler);
        }

        private function loaderCompleteHandler(evt:Event):void{
            img.source = evt.target.content;
        }
```

So you need to use a loader in order to create the bitmap object.

Comment: +1... clearer than the Flex docs, thanks.  Just a nitpick, but wouldn't it be safer to add the "complete" listener before calling **loadBytes**?  If the file is cached and loads right away, the handler may never be called.

Comment: Yep, I agree with you. Not quite sure if this can happen in real life (I think that the call is actually done by the FP after the execution of the function, but I'm not sure).